# Matlab complies C++ file error: fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdafx.h'

Tags: c++, matlab

I downloaded a c++ file called Miguel_2D_unwrapper.cpp at: 
http://read.pudn.com/downloads199/sourcecode/graph/texture_mapping/938065/phase%20unwraping/Miguel_2D_unwrapper.cpp__.htm

When I try to use the C++ code in Matlab (just type: mex Miguel_2D_unwrapper_with_mask.cpp in Matlab command), an error pops up:

> **fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdafx.h': No such file or directory.**

When I try to comment the "stdafx.h" by //#include "stdafx.h", another error pops up:

> Error using mex
>   **LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol mexFunction
>
>   Miguel_2D_unwrapper.lib : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals.**

I use Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1 (C++) combined with 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Professional' for C++ language compilation.

Can someone can have me out on this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you should download the entire RAR archive and not just single files.

Comment: Also, while you may be able to prepare data using MATLAB and then run it through that routine, that file is NOT set up for execution as a MEX-function.

Comment: I already have the whole archive in my current folder in Matlab. I run the C++ code in matlab as suggested by one of the authors for the algorithm. The code should be able to be compiled successfully in Matlab

Answer (score 1):

Your .cpp file uses a number of header files, **stdafx.h** being one of them. That header file is usually created by Visual Studio IDE and is not a part of the standard library nor Windows SDK. You can try removing the following line from your cpp file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

and replacing it with the actual stdafx.h content which in most cases is:

```
#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
```

Another option is to create a **stdafx.h** file yourself, fill it with the above content and put it in the same folder where your cpp file resides.

Comment: I have tried commented #include "stdafx.h" by (//# include "stdafx.h") , but that causes another errors: Error using mex
LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol mexFunction
Miguel_2D_unwrapper.lib : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals. I am not very familiar with C++. The best is to execute the code in matlab.

Comment: @jingweimo The answer addresses your question of how to resolve the `Cannot open include file: 'stdafx.h'` error. As for other errors you should ask a separate question.